# Problemas al ejecutar php artisan migrate; SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] unknow database "xxxxxxxxxx"

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Empiezo a incursionar en el mundo de Laravel y al tratar de hacer una migracion me arroja el error mencionado, he probado muchas respuestas que he visto en otras preguntas aca en la comunidad como cache:clear (por ejempl) pero ninguna soluciona mi error.

La base de datos SI EXISTE la cree desde phpmyadmin y se llama prueba :).

Tengo todos los servicios de Wamp corriendo sin ningun problema.

El error completo es el siguiente:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'prueba' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = prueba and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\wamp64\www\intro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

  1   C:\wamp64\www\intro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'prueba'")

  2   C:\wamp64\www\intro\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=prueba", "root", "", [])
``
```

Comment: Hola, colocaste los datos de acceso a la base de datos en el archivo .env? incluyendo el nombre de la BD?

Comment: mira en tu fichero ' .env ' las credenciales que le pusistes al usuario, password, hostname  y nombre de bd para hacer la conexion

Comment: Si estas dos respuestas tambien las habia visto, y ya revise y efectivamente esta bien configurado el archivo .env; pues solo debi poner el nombre de la BD por que el resto estaba bien:

`DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=prueba
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=`

Comment: Error de novato...revisando mis configuraciones de Wamp no se por que estaba corriendo MySQL en el puerto 3308, ese era mi gran error, de todos modos muchisimas gracias por atender a mi pregunta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando mis configuraciones de Wamp no se por que estaba corriendo MySQL en el puerto 3308, ese era mi gran error, modifique a 3306 y se soluciono el error.